# Counting number of words and letters from txt. file

Tags: python

I am beginner in programming and currently facing issue with simple task. I would need to print words, calculate number of particular words and also number of letters from txt.file. I would appreciate if someone could help me with this:

```
def main():   
    file_name = input("Input file. \n")
    sum_of_letters = 0
    number_words = 0
    try:
        words = open(file_name, "r")
        print("File", file_name ,"includes the following words:")        
        for line in words:
            line = line.rstrip()
            words= line.split()
            for i in words:
                print(i)
                sum_of_letters += len(i)
                number_words += 1
        print("---------------------------------------")
        print("Number of words",number_words ,"ja", sum_of_letters,     "kirjainta.")
        close.words()
    except OSError:
        print("Error observed")
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct but you're using `words` to refer to both the file as well as the words in a single line. I've updated the code below to use different variables:

```
def main():   
    file_name = input("Input file. \n")
    sum_of_letters = 0
    number_words = 0
    try:
        words = open(file_name, "r")
        print("File", file_name ,"includes the following words:")        
        for line in words:
            line = line.rstrip()
            words_in_line = line.split()
            for i in words_in_line:
                print(i)
                sum_of_letters += len(i)
                number_words += 1
        print("---------------------------------------")
        print("Number of words",number_words ,"ja", sum_of_letters,     "kirjainta.")
        words.close()
    except OSError:
        print("Error observed")
```